# Adobe premier preview window shows (and renders after effects compositions as off-center? (pic attached)

Tags: after-effects, premiere

[image]

When importing an after effects comp onto premiere, it shows as off-center, wrapping around so that the right edge shows up on the left side, both in the preview window and in render from Premiere.

Here are my sequence/comp settings:
[image]

My process:

1. Import after effects comp into premiere
2. Premiere shows comp as weirdly off-center. It renders this way too.

Things I've tried:

1. Creating a new sequence/project in premiere
2. Importing after effects comp via import option, via copy paste, or via drag & drop
3. Creating a new after effects comp (just a simple shape layer) and importing that.

Any ideas? Really confused and this is holding up my video production pretty bad right now!

Comment: I have no idea why it would be wrapping like that, but can you actually just render the output and then include that in your project.  If you render to a lossless format, it won't have any loss.  Will potentially be a pretty big output, but it should get you unjammed.

Comment: Thanks AJ. That's what I'll do I think. Thanks for letting me know about the lossless part; I didn't know that and I was worried about it, but now I'm not thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

Check your sequence size in Premiere, and your Comp Size in After Effects are exactly the same.

In Premiere:
Make sure your sequence is selected in the timeline, then
Sequence menu. --> Sequence Settings --> Frame Size

In After Effects:
Maker sure your comp is selected and visible, then
Composition menu --> Composition Settings --> Width/Height.

Check pixel aspect ratios are Square too.

Also: make sure you're viewing your full canvas in Premiere and AE.

Comment: Checked! Added screenshots above. All looks the same? Thanks so much for the help though.